# Can we activate different workflows for different folders in the same site in Plone

Tags: python, plone

In types of the Site setup menu of plone, since we can select different content types and associate it with different workflows simultaneously, Question is is it also possible to set different workflows for different folders in a plone site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out [CMF Placeful Workflow](http://plone.org/products/cmfplacefulworkflow)?

Go to the Plone config screen -> Addon products -> Check "Workflowpolicy (CMFPlacefulWorkflow) 1.5.6" (in my case = Plone 4.1.4).

From the docs on Placeful Workflow:
"CMFPlacefulWorkflow: A Plone product that allows you to define workflow policies that define content type to workflow mappings that can be applied in any sub-folder of your Plone site."

Seems to me that this should do exactly what you want to achieve.

Good luck.